# Using same URL for multiple diferent ROUTES - Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I need to make a angular application to work with same url for multiple routes. Example:

Route 1. Instead of navigating to:

> /partner/urlparameter

Navigate to:

> /partnerurlparameter

Route 2. Instead of navigating to:

> /user/urlparameter

Navigate to:

> /userurlparameter

Where the path is "/" followed by a dynamic value which is the parameter.

Is there a way do achieve that?

Here is how my route is configured:

> { path: '***/partner**/:partnerId*', component: PartnerComponent },
>
> { path: '***/customer**/:customerId*', component: CustomerComponent },

I want to have something like this:

> { path: '*/partner/*:partnerId', component: PartnerComponent },
>
> { path: '*/:customerId*', component: CustomerComponent },

Comment: can you show your routes confi

Comment: Hi Chellappan, I have edited my post and added my routes

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want to achieve, [follow the link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjro81) for same. 
Let me know if there are any changes.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from '../customer/customer.component';
import {PartnerComponent} from '../partner/partner.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'partner/:partnerId', component: PartnerComponent },
  { path: ':customerId', component: CustomerComponent },
  { path: '', component: HelloComponent, pathMatch:'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, CustomerComponent, PartnerComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your reply.. The thing is that I need both routes to point to the same url. Like /:partnerId and /:customerId. I also have other routes so they need to keep working too.